# Error "Cannot find System.ApplicationException in module CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary" when I add functionality for MIDI device input

Tags: c#, .net, midi, visual-studio-2015

I am building an app in Visual Studio using C#.  The aim is to display musical notes on the screen and then get input from a MIDI device.  The app is working up to the point of trying to integrate the MIDI input.  I have included a reference to midi.dll and included the "using midi" line at the top of my code.  However, whenever I try to add a line which references InputDevice, I get the above error when I try to build the app.  The code which seems to be triggering the error is:

```
        InputDevice inputDevice = InputDevice.InstalledDevices[0];
        inputDevice.Open();
        inputDevice.StartReceiving(null);
```

I'd be very grateful for any pointers as to what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 2):

You have probably created a "Universal Windows Application" (Universal App) project. With this type of projects, you are limited in what other libraries you can use. The midi library you try to use is meant to be used with WinForms projects.

Create a WinForms project instead or contact the authors of the MIDI library to see whether they can change it so that it is supported in Universal Apps.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer - I have changed my project to WinForms!